# What the best workaround for run CPanel cron scripts today?

Tags: cron, cpanel

After CPanel updated in 2013 any cron scripts work in jailedshell regardless  account have no shell or jailedshell ... All my scripts working fine when its started as usual under Apache, but I have problem to start the same scripts under cron.

Comment: What is the error from the scripts when executed from cron?

Comment: All CPanel cron scripts run in jailedshell now. It's mean from cron scripts I have no permission to delete files from the disk located outside user account even the disk have chmod 0777.